# Value comparison in <div> using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to compare values coming from database to the value I am entering on my angular 2 model driven form. I want to display a div when the values are not equal. I am trying the logic below but I am unable to make it work. Help will be appreciated.

**View**

```
<form [formGroup]="reguserform" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register()">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control"
               [(ngModel)]="user.Username"
               type="text" id="Username"
               formControlName="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"
         *ngIf="reguserform.controls.Username.touched && reguserform.controls.Username.errors">
        <div *ngIf="reguserform.controls.Username.errors.required"
             class="alert alert-danger">
            Please enter a valid Username...
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let r of rusers">
            <div *ngIf="r.Username == user.Username" class="alert alert-danger">Username is taken</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Component**

```
getUsers() {
    this.authenticationService.getRegUser().subscribe(
        res => this.rusers = res
    );
}
```

Everything is fine from the db end the object is being logged in console too but at the time of comparison no div is shown.

Comment: your *ngFor="let r of rusers" is in another *ngIf *ngIf="reguserform.controls.Username.touched && reguserform.controls.Username.errors">.. inside *ngFor only works when outside is true. how are you checking that condition. ?? how are you getting user.Username...

Comment: I put it out of *ngIf condition too but did'nt make any difference. And I am using ngModel so user.Username is always in sync with the UI

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works in general, but that `*ngIf="reguserform.controls.Username.touched && reguserform.controls.Username.errors"` isn't true!

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
        <form [formGroup]="reguserform" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register()">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Username">Username</label>
              <input class="form-control"
                     [(ngModel)]="user.Username"
                     type="text" id="Username"
                     formControlName="Username" />
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngFor="let r of rusers">
                  <div *ngIf="r.Username == user.Username" class="alert alert-danger">Username is taken</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public reguserform: FormGroup; // our model driven form

  user = {};
  rusers = [
    { Username: 'mxii' },
    { Username: 'test' },
    { Username: 'peter' }
  ];

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reguserform = this._fb.group({
      Username: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(1)]]
    });
  }
}
```

See my live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/SnHfoAL2dnuwKkrFYGzE?p=preview

Comment: +1 for the plunker. I have implemented the code exactly the same as in plunker but It is not working in my project I don't what is the problem here :/ I am looking into that and I am confident this solution will work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

When you write `res => this.rusers = res` I guess you put the http response in your variable. It's not an iterable object. Maybe you need to write this :

```
getUsers() {
    this.rusers = this.authenticationService.getRegUser().map(
        res => res.json() 
    );
}
```